# QGIS label formula

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, labeling, qgis-processing

I have the formula below to make my labels:

```
"operator" || '\n' || "well_name" || ' ' || "well_num"  ||  '\n'  || "footagens"  || ' ' || 'F' || "ns" || 'L' || ' ' || '-' || ' ' || "footageew" || ' ' || 'F' || "ew" || 'L'  || ' ' || '(' || "qtr1" || ')' ||  '\n'  || '(' || "wellstatus" || ')'
```

My problem is some of these have "NULL" attributes or a "0". I need this to be able to handle NULL and 0 and on the label make it display "N/A"

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `CASE WHEN...` expressions?

Answer (score 3):

For your case is better to use the [`format`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format) function, and you can create an array with all the fields value to replace them when "NULL" or "0" with "N/A".

```
with_variable(
    'fields',
    array_foreach(
        array(
            "operator",
            "well_name",
            "well_num",
            "footagens",
            "ns",
            "footageew",
            "ew",
            "qtr1",
            "well_status"
        ),
        if(@element is NULL OR @element = 0, 'N/A', @element)
    ),
    format(
        '%1 \n %2 %3 \n %4 F %5 L - %6 F %7 L (%8) \n (%9)',
        @fields[0],
        @fields[1],
        @fields[2],
        @fields[3],
        @fields[4],
        @fields[5],
        @fields[6],
        @fields[7],
        @fields[8]
    )
)
```

Is not the best approach but it works.

Another way could be create a function to format arrays. Try this.

Open the field calculator go to the [Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor) tab and click the button New File[image: New File], then paste this code in the new file and click the **Load and Run Functions** [image: Load and Run Functions]

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

import re
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='String', referenced_columns=[])
def format_array(string, s_values, feature, parent):
    s_keys = sorted(set(re.findall('%\d+', string)))
    for s_key in s_keys:
        string = string.replace(s_key, '{%s}' % (s_key))
    return string.format(**dict(zip(s_keys, s_values)))
```

Then return to the Expression Tab and paste this expression.

```
with_variable(
    'fields',
    array_foreach(
        array(
            -- list of fields to format in the string
            "operator",
            "well_name",
            "well_num",
            "footagens",
            "ns",
            "footageew",
            "ew",
            "qtr1",
            "well_status"
        ),
        if(@element IS NULL OR @element = 0, 'N/A', @element) -- values to replace
    ),
    format_array( -- format the array with replaced values in the string
        '%1 \n %2 %3 \n %4 F %5 L - %6 F %7 L (%8) \n (%9)',
        @fields
    )
)
```

Comment: This worked great but I noticed a problem with my original question. Even when it replaces with N/A there are left over items. I ended up getting it to work with the code below, but is there a better way? 

`"operator" + '\n' + "well_name" + ' ' + "well_num" + '\n' +if(footageew=0,'N/A', + to_string("footagens") + ' ' + 'F' + "ns" + 'L' + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + to_string("footageew") + ' ' + 'F' + "ew" + 'L') + ' ' + '(' + "qtr1" + ')' + '\n' + '(' + "wellstatus"`

Thank you so much for this :)

Comment: What items are not being formatted in the string?

Comment: @JoshKelly try `if(@element IS NULL OR @element = 0 OR @element = '', 'N/A', @element)` in Mayo's expression, sometimes a field looks NULL but is actually a zero-length string

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if(field = 0,'N/A',coalesce(field, 'N/A'))` or better replace the NULL values in your datasource, or create a view with ‚`N/A` instead of NULL.